# Contains search using lodash.js

Tags: javascript, search, underscore.js, contains

```
var codes = [
{id: 1, code: '123'},
{id: 2, code: '14123'},
{id: 3, code: '556'},
{id: 4, code: '71239'},
{id: 5, code: '289'},
];

var filterCodes = _.filter(codes, function (o) {
  return o.code ? _.includes(o.code, '123') : false
});
```

Output will be : '123','14123','71239'

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question says `lodash`, tags say `underscore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you are loking for all the codes and not entire object, which has "123" in them.

#### array.forEach

```js
var codes = [{id: 1, code: '123'},{id: 2, code: '14123'},{id: 3, code: '556'},{id: 4, code: '71239'},{id: 5, code: '289'}];

var result = [];
codes.forEach(function(o){
  o.code && o.code.indexOf('123') >= 0 && result.push(o.code)
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Due to OP's code having `return o.code ?...`, I suspect that each object does not necessarily have a `code` property

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother with Lodash for this? Also, I *think* you're missing a *map* step...

```js
const codes = [{"id":1,"code":"123"},{"id":2,"code":"14123"},{"id":3,"code":"556"},{"id":4,"code":"71239"},{"id":5,"code":"289"}]

const filterCodes = codes
  .filter(o => typeof o.code === 'string' && o.code.includes('123'))
  .map(o => o.code)
console.info(filterCodes)
```

Comment: Since you are already using ES6, you can even try [string.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Also, if this is what OP is looking for, even his code would do the same. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rajesh fair call. It's so hard to keep up with all these new methods :)

Comment: @Rajesh I think I figured what OP was missing

Comment: And whats that?

Comment: @Rajesh mapping the array of objects to an array of code strings